# App Bundle Identifier Archiving Issue

Tags: ios

I have got my developer's license and I wanted to change the current bundle identifier to my new developer account so I deleted the identifier I had and added the new one.

I have changed it in the `info.plist` and all of that but for some reason every time I try and archive my app so that my friends can start testing it in test flight it gives me an error and tells me that 
*`I need to verify my bundle identifier.`*

What do I need to do to fix this? Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: I can't help you with your issue, but happy birthday!

Comment: What error you are getting? can you post

Comment: @AnilVarghese I get "iTunes Store operation failed.  No suitable application record were found. Verify your Bundle Identifier is correct"

Comment: Check the bundle identifier of the application record in [itunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app)

Comment: @AnilVarghese Thats what everything says to do but the problem is that I have never uploaded the app before.  I didn't get a developer account until 2 hours ago.

Comment: You need to create an app record in itunes connect first.

Comment: Ohh that would make sense thanks

Comment: Have you created development and distribution profile for your app?
until you're not able to put it on itunes connect for testflight

Comment: @MrugeshTank I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Good, and Happy birthday!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login your Apple Developer account in Xcode Preference, and let Xcode manage it automatically.

[image]